# ActionScript 3.0 Dynamic Text disappearing with button event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So, I am having an issue with ActionScript 3.0. I double checked, and ensured that there is nothing missing. However, I am coming up with an interesting result.

I have a dynamic text, which has an instance of `varMoney`. Also have a button instance called `btnTen_percent`.

When, I click the button; it should update the text saying something else. Instead it simply disappear.

```
public function startShop():void {
  btnTen_percent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tenPercent);
}

private function tenPercent(e:MouseEvent):void {
  trace("10 percent");
  varMoney.text = "1000";
}
```

So I was wondering, where did it went wrong?

Comment: Make sure your font is embedded...

Comment: ... and that the embedded font has the glyphs that are need for your text.

Comment: And check if the font has numbers in it and your text field is not restricted to characters only or something like that. Do you see any other text when you set the value ?